# How to eliminate repeating case or decode statement multiple times in SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example:

```
SELECT a,
  IF (c = DECODE(b, "foo1", "bar1", "foo2", "bar2") THEN c ELSE 0),
  IF (d != DECODE(b, "foo1", "bar1", "foo2", "bar2") THEN d ELSE 2),
  IF (e = DECODE(b, "foo1", "bar1", "foo2", "bar2") THEN e ELSE 5)
FROM x
```

Seems like there should be a less repetitive way to do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
SELECT 
a,
IF (c = b THEN c ELSE 0),
IF (d != b THEN d ELSE 2),
IF (e = b THEN e ELSE 5)
FROM
(SELECT a, DECODE(b, "foo1", "bar1", "foo2", "bar2") b, c, d, e from x);
```

Comment: where are you getting the values of c, d & e?

Comment: nvm -- i edited them in there for you -- but moderator has to approve first.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a,
  DECODE( c, b_decoded, c, 0 ),
  DECODE( d, b_decoded, 2, d ),
  DECODE( e, b_decoded, e, 5 )
FROM (SELECT a, c, d, e, DECODE(b, "foo1", "bar1", "foo2", "bar2") b_decoded FROM x)
```